# How I can request a local url in my app engine application?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, url, blob

I am using Blobs to store json files for my application. What I am trying to achieve is to request an internal url of my application in order to get the relevant file. I have tried urllib, urllib2, urlfetch but every time I am getting a 5 second `DeadlineExceededError: 5 timed out` error. Is there a way to retrieve my blob in my get request or an alternative for retrieving my data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch a url while building a request in python AppEngine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916204/how-to-fetch-a-url-while-building-a-request-in-python-appengine) - please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make HTTP requests to yourself in order to read data from the blobstore - you can simply use the [BlobReader API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass.html).

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't on the development server (but will work on the production server) because its single threaded and you can't do a request to yourself from within a request.

There are several workarounds for your issue:

1. Use the file write API to store the data.
2. Use the multithread dev_server (required to switch to python 2.7 + HRD)
3. Store the file asynchronously using queues or deferred.

Comment: The point is to retrieve the data not to store them, but I got the point, the project was initialized in python 2.7 but threadsafe was disabled I am looking about how to port it so while I am building the response I can hit a concurrent request for the blob.