# How to fetch a url while building a request in python AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

In order to be able to build a get response when somebody hits `/show_data/` url of my service, while I am building it I want to fetch the url `/retrieve_data/` from the same service. How can I fire it up in a different thread so I can avoid the DeadLineExceeded errors I am receiving? I am using python 2.7, with `threadsafe=true`.

so I have something like this for the `/show_data/` handler:

```
def get(self):
  url = '/retrieve_data/'
  data_from_my_service = urlfetch.fetch(url)
  do_something_with_data(data_from_my_service)
  self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: why do you need to fetch the url when you have the option to use the service directly without the http roundtrip?

Comment: Because my data (json) are stored as a blob. So I need to serve it.

Comment: There's no need to use an HTTP request to yourself, regardless of how your data is stored - just use the appropriate API to retrieve the data directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [urlfetch async API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) (no need to involve threads).